# String Array Method not Returning the Array Object - Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, pageobjects

Please Find my code, its not Returning the Array object value, its return only one array object

```
public String[] verify_userRole(String[] Expected_role) {
        String[] actual_role = new String[4];
        String first;
        WebElement role_table = driver.findElement(By
                .xpath("//*[@id='tblListView']/tbody[1]"));
        List<WebElement> allRows = role_table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

        for (WebElement row : allRows) {
            List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

            for (WebElement cell : cells) {
                first = cell.getText().toString();
                actual_role = new String[] {first};

                }
        }
        return actual_role;
    }
```

variable first its contain Four values ("name","name1","name2","name3")
after convert this string value into an array (actual_role) then its return only one value ("name")

Please clarify what is the Problem for the above code

Answer (score 3):

You re-initialize string array on every step in your loop.

You should do it only once.

```
   ArrayList<String> actual_role = new ArrayList<String>( )
   for (WebElement row : allRows) {
        List<WebElement> cells = row.findElements(By.tagName("td"));

        for (WebElement cell : cells) {
            first = cell.getText().toString();
            actual_role.add(first);

        }
    }

    return (String[]) actual_role.toArray( new String[ actual_role.size() ] );
```

BTW, I've converted your example to use intermediary ArrayList, because you don't know the actual data size, and it's error-prone to reinitialize arrays on the fly.

If the signature of the method, you are implementing, is not dictated by external framework, I suggest you use `List<String>` as a return type instead of `String[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You always instantiate your array inside the loop:

```
actual_role = new String[] {first};
```

try instead:

```
actual_role[i] = first;
```

When i is the current index.